# How to draw path superposition with different color on leaflet.js?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polyline-decorator

I would like to draw several paths from same coordinates on a `leaflet.js` map. I have thought about making the gap between paths with trigonometric computations, but it's too complex to deal with teh zoom level, translate GPS coordinates to a vector, etc.

The drawing I have now is like this (another path is under the green path):

[image]

And I would like something like that:

[image]

Of course, the coordinates, angle and zoomlevel can change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably be interested in [Leaflet Polyline Offset](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineOffset) plugin:

> This plugin adds to Leaflet `Polyline`s the ability to be drawn with a relative pixel offset, without modifying their actual `LatLng`s. The offset value can be either negative or positive, for left- or right-side offset, and remains constant across zoom levels.

[Bus lines demo](http://bbecquet.github.io/Leaflet.PolylineOffset/examples/example_bus.html)

[image: Screenshot of Leaflet Polyline Offset plugin bus lines demo]